# 'Where' Query in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a table Order(:id, :number). I need to find count of those records from Order whose column(:number) value is not -1(default). I wrote :

```
Order.where(:number != -1).count
```

But this gives the value Order.count still. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass arguments to `where` properly. In this case, you should pass it as string:

```
Order.where('numer != ?', -1).count
```

or use `not`:

```
Order.where.not(number: -1).count
```